# When I paint on one object, the color shows up on another but on the uv map of the painted-on object

Tags: texturing

When I try to paint on the white part at the bottom in blue, the color shows up on the black part at the top[image]

The part where the blue shows up is exactly where the uv map of the white part is.[image][image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the island margins upon unwrapping?

Comment: @NoStepOnSnek Not sure how or why... but that worked